# How to use isDev within a plugin?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

How can I use isDev within my plugin?

Unfortunately I do not understand how to use it.
[Link to context documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context)

This is what I tried:

## /plugins/axios.js

```
export default function({ $axios, redirect, req }) {
  if (context.isDev) (
    console.log('Running as dev')
    ...

  )
```

How can I acces **isDev**?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

```
export default function({ $axios, redirect, req, isDev }) {
  if (isDev) (
    console.log('Running as dev')
    ...
  )
```

Just add isDev to your parameters. (Because it is within the context)